# WebStorm does not show auto complete for pure JS libraries in a TypeScript context

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm, couchbase

Let’s say I have a JS library “A”. I can use it in a JS project in WebStorm and all available methods are shown in auto complete correctly.

Then I use the same library “A”, but it does not have a @type file. When I import it and try to use it in TypeScript context, no auto completion is shown.

How can I configure to show JS auto completion in this case?

---

Please only read below if the above information is Not clear enough.

Actually the problem is more complicated than that. I’m using couchbase js lib in my node.js TypeScript project. Couchbase js lib actually has a type file for me to use (download from npm). But the type file is not updated with the latest couchbase js, specifically the `cluster.authenticate` method. When I’m under the outdated type file and try to use this method, it doesn’t even compile since the method does not exist in the type file. So I have to remove the type file and use the pure JS library.

Any idea how to solve this?

Attach two screenshot to illustrate 
[image]
[image]

Comment: to be able to import .js in your TypeScript file, you need adding ` "allowJs": true` to your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @lena I’m able to import, just the autocomplete does not work.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out whether your issue is Couchbase-specific or not, as you seem to have a general problem. Can you elaborate? Also, VS Code might work better for you all around.

Comment: @theMayer it’s not couchbase specific, I think all JS library without (up to date) typing file will experience the same issue. I tried to use VS code for another project but I can’t even get my JS auto complete to work.. it was a frustrating experience...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039121/webstorm-does-not-show-auto-complete-for-pure-js-libraries-in-a-typescript-conte#comment89070339_51039121), `tsconfig.json` should have `allowJs: true`.

However, when using modules from `node_modules`, `maxNodeModuleJsDepth` needs to be set as well, e.g. `maxNodeModuleJsDepth: 2`. The issue is this [defaults to 0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#maxNodeModuleJsDepth) so only `d.ts` files are considered for files inside `node_modules` despite enabling `allowJs`.

In my case a package had no type definitions, a single main file which imports other files only one level deep. So to get autocomplete info I had to set `maxNodeModuleJsDepth: 2`.